# Using xargs to redirect input file parameter to a bash command

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I have a python command (that I cannot modify) that takes as input a file as and output the result:

```
  $ echo '{"sentence": "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"}' > examples.jsonl
  $ python -m allennlp.run predict https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/ner-model-2018.02.12.tar.gz examples.jsonl
```

The usage is the following:

```
usage: python -m allennlp.run [command] predict [-h]
                                                [--output-file OUTPUT_FILE]
                                                [--weights-file WEIGHTS_FILE]
                                                [--batch-size BATCH_SIZE]
                                                [--silent]
                                                [--cuda-device CUDA_DEVICE]
                                                [-o OVERRIDES]
                                                [--include-package INCLUDE_PACKAGE]
                                                [--predictor PREDICTOR]
                                                archive_file input_file
```

Is there a way in `bash` to redirect the input to this command directly instead of echoing to a file? It seems that the command does not support `pipe` from stdin by the way, so the following will not work:

```
$ echo '{"sentence": "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"}' | python -m allennlp.run predict https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/ner-model-2018.02.12.tar.gz
```

I have tried using `xargs` but I don't figure out the right way to handle the `input_file` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `allennlp` needs a file (i.e. cannot simply read from /dev/stdin), then this will work:

```
echo '{"sentence": "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"}' | 
  parallel --pipe -N1 --cat python -m allennlp.run predict https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/ner-model-2018.02.12.tar.gz {}
```

It is especially useful if you are going to run many `allennlp` with different input:

```
(echo '{"sentence": "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"}';
 echo '{"sentence": "its insatiable appetite is tempered by its fear of light."}';
 echo '{"sentence": "You were eaten by a grue"}';) |
  parallel --pipe -N1 --cat python -m allennlp.run predict https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/ner-model-2018.02.12.tar.gz {}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the most affordable solution. I will just add a reference to the GNU parallel jobs execution command: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 3):

Creates a temporary file descriptor that is deallocated when the command exits. It will work on most programs and replaces the argument of the file.

```
<(echo hello)
```

example

```
grep h <(echo hello)


python -m allennlp.run predict https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/ner-model-2018.02.12.tar.gz  <( echo '{"sentence": "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"}' > examples.jsonl )
```

Comment: When does that solution fail? It fails if `allennlp` seeks into the file. If called from `bash`, then this might work, too: `echo ... | python -m allennlp... /dev/stdin` (but this will also fail if `allennlp` seeks).